# Pyperclip not copying text. Copies "qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin"

Tags: python

I have a simple program I'm trying to run from Al Sweigart's book Automate the Boring Stuff, it's supposed to copy text and paste it with each new line having a '*' at the beginning.  Here's the code...

```
#! /usr/bin/python3
# bulletPointAdder.py - Adds Wikipedia bullet points to the start
# of each line of text on the clipboard.

import pyperclip
text = pyperclip.paste()

# Separate lines and add stars.
lines = text.split('\n')
for i in range(len(lines)):    # loop through all indexes for "lines" list
    lines[i] = '* ' + lines[i] # add star to each string in "lines" list
text = '\n'.join(lines)
pyperclip.copy(text)
```

When I run this code nothing happens and my right click is temporarily disabled.  It only seems to return if I open a windown and click on 'File' or 'Edit'.  If I run the code in the terminal directly I get this...

```
>>> import pyperclip
>>> text = pyperclip.paste()
qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
>>> lines = text.split('\n')
>>> for i in range(len(lines)):
...  lines[i] = '* ' + lines[i]
... 
>>> text = '\n'.join(lines)
>>> pyperclip.copy(text)
>>> print(text)
* qt5ct: using qt5ct plugin
```

I'm not sure where the 'qt5ct' text is coming from as this wasn't what I copied.  Does anyone have any idea what's causing this?  I'm on Manjaro Linux if that helps.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please post it as an answer, not an edit to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Update:  After a bunch of searches online I could't figure out what was going on.  I assumed it was something to do with Manjaro so I set up a virtual environment of Linux Mint.  After getting everything set up and pyperclip installed I ran the same code and this time got a *Traceback* error saying

```
Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
For more information, please visit https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introdcution.html#not-implemented-error
```

Ok, so now I had something to work with at least and could see it's something to with the way the computer copies and pastes.  So I went to the website listed in the error and there were some copy-paste programs to choose from.  I went with 'xsel' and reran the program, worked.  Did the same thing on my manjaro machine and it works.